# Subscribe box depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, interstitial

I have set subscribe popup box, but now because of Google penalty I need to have 2 different one for mobile and desktop. Function is set in function.php and ideally would like to keep it there but not sure how to gpo around it.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'show_subscribe_popup' );       

function show_subscribe_popup(){
    if(is_front_page()){
        //$subscribe_popup = '
        //';    
        //echo $subscribe_popup;
        include('inc/popup_form_test.php');
    }
}
```

I created to form files and trying to incorporate `var viewportWidth = $(window).width();`

Any suggestions please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I manage to sole it by using wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() so if anybody have problem with new google penalty rule here is the solution

Comment: May I suggest you post that as an answer (rather than as a comment) so that others can find it easier.